# how to copy pandas dataframe to vertica with airflow?

Tags: python, pandas, airflow, vertica, vertica-python

when I run the following function:

```
def write_df_to_vertica(conn: Cursor, df: pd.DataFrame):
    query = """COPY temp_data.test(coumn1, coumn2, coumn3) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' """
    conn.copy(query, df.to_csv(index=False, header=False))
```

it works, and the data is written to vertica db.

**However** when I call this function from `PythonOperator` in a `AirFlow` dag, the data isn't written to the db.

Why? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe?

```
`pandas_to_vertica(df, 
              cursor=None, 
              name: str = "", 
              schema: str = "", 
              dtype: dict = {}, 
              parse_n_lines: int = 10000, 
              temp_path: str = "", 
              insert: bool = False,)`
```

this is the format for it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem,
and I don't know why, but this did work for me

```html
from airflow.providers.vertica.hooks.vertica import VerticaHook

hook = VerticaHook(vertica_conn_id=<your connection>)
conn = hook.get_conn()
cursor = conn.cursor()

df = pd.DataFrame(<your own data from dict>)
df_csv = df.to_csv(sep='|', index=False)

cursor.copy(f"COPY {<schema.table>} FROM STDIN PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter='|');", df_csv)
cursor.close()
```

You may also try `ABORT ON ERROR NO COMMIT` to see some undetected errors while copying the file, such as wrong data types.